# Difference between record levels in "sound settings" and in "pulse audio volume"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am confused when trying to set up the correct recording level using a Behringer UCA222 usb codec. If I adjust the level in "sound settings" I can reduce the input level to avoid clipping. However, if I reduce the level in pulse audio volume instead, the clipping remains. Do these two controls act in different places in the audio chain? If so, where?

What also puzzles me is that the codec does not seem to have a capture level control to allow the level to be reduced before ADC so how does the "sound setting" level avoid clipping?

Any light gratefully received.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

pulse audio:  It allows you to do advanced operations on your sound data as it passes between your application and your hardware. Things like transferring the audio to a different machine. As here I can see in the question you are using a USB device to record the sound, I would suggest you just make the changes in Sound setting From pulse audio to USB audio for both the In and Out setting and try